# Benefits of 'Optimize code' option in Visual Studio build

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-construction, build, compiler-optimization

Much of our C# release code is built with the 'Optimize code' option turned off. I believe this is to allow code built in Release mode to be debugged more easily.

Given that we are creating fairly simple desktop software which connects to backend Web Services, (ie. not a particularly processor-intensive application) then what if any sort of performance hit might be expected?

And is any particular platform likely to be worse affected? Eg. multi-processor / 64 bit.

Comment: I've seen this fallacy run into a _lot_ in older shops that are still stuck with a C/C++ culture as they (claim) to be trying to shift to newer technologies.

Comment: @Greg D - Interesting, I would have thought that the C++ culture would prefer optimisation - or is that not what you meant?

Comment: @gt:  The C++ culture that I've run into most frequently _claims_ to prefer optimization and "fast code," but most such claims are based on superstition and irrational fear of anything new or different.  I don't deny that the culture I'm referring to is dysfunctional, but I do think it's widespread outside this particular shop as well.  The number of people who, in spite of all evidence to the contrary, insist that _their_ C++ code has superior perf characteristics to some reasonably written C# code, e.g., is astounding.  I've heard "I'll manage my own memory, thankyouverymuch" too often.

Comment: Besides the debug environment, does this option in release mode affect have any caveats?

Comment: It's 2020 now and I am here because my C# Xamarin.Android app breaks if I *do not * check this box!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The full details are available at http://blogs.msdn.com/jaybaz_ms/archive/2004/06/28/168314.aspx.

In brief...

> In managed code, the JITter in the runtime does nearly all the optimization.  The difference in generated IL from this flag is pretty small.

Comment: I'm not sure why that quote is important.  The JITter's optimizations are affected by the flag, even if the generated IL is not, so the flag will have an impact on performance.  The original question was about the magnitude of that difference.

Comment: Also, i don't believe that link to be useful at all. Its a conversation in 2004 where the guy misinterprets the role of the JIT vs code optimisations.

Answer (score 34):

You are the only person who can answer the "performance hit" question. Try it both ways, measure the performance, and see what happens. The hit could be enormous or it could be nonexistant; no one reading this knows whether "enormous" to you means one microsecond or twenty minutes.

If you're interested in what optimizations are done by the C# compiler -- rather than the jitter -- when the optimize switch is on, see:

http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do.aspx

Comment: Current link https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/06/11/what-does-the-optimize-switch-do/

Answer (score 6):

In fact, there is a difference, sometimes quite significant. What can really affect the performance (as it is something that JIT does not fully take care of):

- Unnecessary local variables (i.e., bigger stack frames for each call)
- Too generic conditional instructions, JIT translates them in quite a straightforward manner.
- Unnecessary branching (also not served well by a JIT - after all, it does not have too much time to do all the smart optimisations)

  So, if you're doing something numerical - turn on the optimisation. Otherwise you won't see any difference at all.

Comment: Your final point isn't self-evident. It's entirely possible that non-numerical code could benefit from optimisations like deep-inlining. Without a concrete source, I don't see a reason to assume one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

The optimizations done by the compiler are fairly low level and shouldn't affect your users' experience.

If you'd like to quantify the optimization on your application, simply profile a non-optimized and an optimized build and compare the results.

Comment: I've noticed debuggers skip lines when it's present. This in VS 2013 and 15 by the way! Sometimes I just toggle it off locally for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 2):

I find that with complex, CPU intensive code (the code i'm using is a Monte Carlo simulation that can spawn enough threads to 100% utilize a computer. This was tested in a 36 core environment) the performance hit can be up to 4 times higher!  A simulation that takes 2 hours will take about 9 hours without the optimization flag. (the paths are about 500,000 and for each paths there are 500 steps for around 2000 different objects with highly complex calculation on each objects).